# cPanel Email Pipe Program

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I want to run a PHP program when receiving emails, and so far, I've had no luck. I have this code in the "Set Default Address" page on cPanel:

[image]

mailhandler.php contains the following PHP code:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/php -q
<?php

  $DataBase = array(
                      'host' => 'localhost',
                      'port' => 3306,
                      'username' => 'dbusername',
                      'password' => 'dbpassword',
                      'database' => 'dbdatabase',
                    );

  // Establish secure database connection
  $DB = @new mysqli($DataBase['host'], $DataBase['username'], $DataBase['password'], $DataBase['database'], $DataBase['port']);


  $DB->query("INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES('Mail received!')");
?>
```

I've tried running the PHP script from the browser, and the text "Mail received!" is stored into the table. However, when I send a mail, nothing happens. I receive the email on my email account, but nothing is inserted into the database.

**Edit:** I am receiving the following mail when trying to send a mail to my server:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> pipe to |/home/MY USERNAME HERE/public_html/mailhandler.php
>       generated by MY EMAIL HERE
>       local delivery failed
>
> The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:
>
> ------ pipe to |/home/MY USERNAME HERE/public_html/mailhandler.php
>          generated by MY EMAIL HERE ------
>
> Could not exec '/home/MY USERNAME HERE/public_html/mailhandler.php'
>
> ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
>
> Return-path:  Received: from
>   mail-qa0-f67.google.com ([209.85.216.67]:64353)
>           by SERVER URL HERE with esmtps (TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128)
>           (Exim 4.82)
>           (envelope-from )
>           id 1WeXDD-0006Pe-Nn
>           for MY EMAIL HERE; Mon, 28 Apr 2014 02:06:17 +0400 Received: by mail-qa0-f67.google.com with SMTP id dc16so744105qab.2
>           for ; Sun, 27 Apr 2014 15:06:28 -0700 (PDT) DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
>           d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
>           h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
>           bh=uuzTLjs2Sa8uqU2HBL4i1frXIc2i13Cxtg9X0Mykahg=;
>           b=A/0fGQwjV6g1G+TBL12DIASjLqcl9h7jD9LOFKEm6MX0YL4uFa3ZRJ9zdou9dio9Hf
>            yjPJv+yTFjV3W7mzydQc7pvkyTSRpHPbxN/B7yySagzB5PPMbrhebLGJoNTBSrtFaidS
>            4Zax/qtOoj/GRnNf9srmtq8IQS4Np1EKJWn+uiKTxDBj2IPU3p2ng8ufkW8cKehHVJFR
>            A7DOm9v26JZq3NRpNt8ct7yuSsOp8Nwqwe49p9703FvoePXvu6on2GZwiNTlD6fcJjf5
>            /wtwHpMqu8YVZ0Ehx0GXNgqDtpsINrmgIAil9dPfdTF7VtJiIIq9x9sm6yAPzUtTQTBw
>            9gUA== MIME-Version: 1.0 X-Received: by 10.140.26.243 with SMTP id 106mr11307188qgv.91.1398636388049;  Sun, 27 Apr 2014 15:06:28
>   -0700 (PDT) Received: by 10.224.131.198 with HTTP; Sun, 27 Apr 2014 15:06:28 -0700 (PDT) Date: Mon, 28 Apr 2014 00:06:28 +0200 Message-ID:
>   
>   Subject: heeei From: MY NAME HERE  To:
>   MY EMAIL HERE Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=001a11c00c9814689304f80d6998
>
> --001a11c00c9814689304f80d6998 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> test
>
> --001a11c00c9814689304f80d6998 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> test
>
> --001a11c00c9814689304f80d6998--

Comment: Looks like it expects the full path: `/home/USERNAME/public_html/mailhandler.php`, have you tried this (replacing USERNAME with your username) of course

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't want to share my username or other data on my server. The username is correct xD

Comment: Are you sure the path to use `/usr/local/lib/php` is proper?

Comment: phpinfo says so, Ohgodwhy. See the updated file. Added the returned email I get when sending

Comment: Try changing permissions of file to 777

Comment: The permissions wasn't the bug. Fixed it now, was something in the php.ini file. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should post the answer and then accept it, to help others in the future.

Comment: Teskon, could you write an answer regarding what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

'Could not exec' likely means you don't have the permissions set correctly on that PHP file.  You need to make sure that PHP file is executable.  755 should be good.

I realize this is an old thread but I recently did all of this and figured I'd post in case someone else ran across it.

Comment: This worked for me. File was 644 by default. Changed it to 755 and it worked well.